# when i try to install my apk its doesn't show the list of permission

Tags: android, android-permissions

I created an apk using the android studio and it is working successfully but when the time of installing it shows "It does not require any special access" but in the  manifest, there is `PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALL`

[image]

Comment: can we see the manifest

Comment: What is your target SDK ?

Comment: If you explicitly requested `PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALL`, that's gonna be a problem because it doesn't exist. There is a `PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS` though. This could of course me a copy-paste issue, but either way you need to create a [mcve]

Comment: Without including some code of what you are doing in order to obtain the permission, its a little harder to provide proper help. There is more involved than just adding the permissions in the manifest.

Comment: You need to ask for permission explicitly in your java file rather than just decalared in manifest..yes its important to declare in manifest too..but u need to ask for it explicitly..